# Using content ID and Slug in URI in Laravel route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Currently I have routes of the type:

```
lesson/{id}
```

and I would like to be able to use a slug as well in the path:

```
lesson/learn-how-to-play
```

so that both `lesson/1` and `lesson/learn-how-to-play` bring me to the same page.

I Store the `slug` as a field in the `Lesson` table.

I have seen ways to use either, or but not both at the same time.

Then is is possible to call `route('lesson.index', $lesson_id)` and have it render the URI with the slug rather then the lesson ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to filter your routes with numeric ids:

```
Route::get(
   'lesson/{id}', 
   ['as' => 'lesson.index', 'uses' => 'ControllerName@byId']
)->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

and then use the slug one as a fallback:

```
Route::get(
    'lesson/{slug}', 
    ['as' => 'lesson.index', 'uses' => 'ControllerName@bySlug']
);
```